# Does memory address always refer to one byte, not one bit?

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture

1. Can you confirm that memory address in a PC is alway pointing to one
   byte (8 bits)?
2. If a float number needs 32 bits in memory, does the
   computer allocate 4-sequential bytes (32 bits total) to represent
   that number?

Comment: If you address single bits instead of bytes, you immediately cut your effective address space by 8x. Why would you want that?

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, a memory address always contains a byte address. I can't think of a single CPU architecture that supports bit-level addressing.
2. A CPU native float will always be stored in sequential memory locations. This is true for all native CPU types.

Comment: In the other direction, I think some old architectures only had word-addressable memory.  Old ARM used the low bits of an address to specify a rotation, rather than a byte offset within a word.  Re: floats, apparently some systems used a different endianness for floats than for integers, because C has a separate `__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__` macro.  (But of course they are still stored in 4 contiguous bytes, which apparently is all the question was asking).

Comment: ARM can provide bit-band regions — sections of the memory map which map word addresses to bit addresses. This is primarily intended to support atomic operations at bit granularity for I/O devices. MIPS provides similar functionality with Atomically Set Bit within Byte and Atomically Clear Bit within Byte instructions (part of its MCU Application Specific Extension), a three-bit immediate field specifies the bit and the operation is architecturely defined as a non-interruptable byte read-modify-write. I think some 8-bit ISAs have support for bit-granular accesses.

Comment: HP Saturn found in calculators uses 4-bit address (nibble) instead of byte, but had 64-bit registers. 
Some old mainframe and supercomputer architectures can only address their native word size. Examples include 36-bit (IBM 701, DEC PDP-10) and 60-bit (CDC Cyber). 
Modern DSPs often lack the ability to address bytes as well, preferring to handle only floating point and some limited integers.

Answer (score 3):

1. let's make it more generic and say "computing unit" instead of "PC" so the answer will be YES. Some Designers do that for a purpose of performance.

EX: In ARM cortex m4 processor there are some memory space that is reserved for bit access (i.e. each address in that space contains only 1 bit). Read about bit banding for more details.

2. Yes absolutely and that is applicable for all data types (int, string, ..)